# Conditional $inc in MongoDB query

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, database, nosql

I have a survey system with documents like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("555b0b33ed26911e080102c4"),
    "question" : "survey",
    "subtitle" : "",
    "answers" : [ 
        {
            "title" : "option 1",
            "color" : "#FFEC00",
            "code" : "opt1",
            "_id" : ObjectId("555b0b33ed26911e080102ce"),
            "votes" : 0,
            "visible" : true
        }, 
        {
            "title" : "option 2",
            "color" : "#0bb2ff",
            "code" : "opt2",
            "_id" : ObjectId("555b0b33ed26911e080102cd"),
            "votes" : 0,
            "visible" : true
        }
    ]
}
```

Now, I'm working on submit vote, so I need to increase 'votes' field for an specific survey (depending on option selected by user).

My problem is: I can have multiple documents like that, so **how can I `$inc` field `votes` inside this array for an specific document?** I tried this query (based on [this website](http://www.wiredprairie.us/blog/index.php/archives/1895)), but it didn't work:

```
db.bigsurveys.update(
   {_id: ObjectId('555b0b33ed26911e080102c4'), 'answers.$.code' : 'opt1'}, 
   { $inc : { 'answers.$.votes' : 1 } }
)
```

The main problem here is that I can have multiple documents like this. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [$elemMatch](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) and postional operator  [$](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/) to update query as :

```
db.bigsurveys.update({
   "_id": ObjectId("555b0b33ed26911e080102c4"),
   "answers": {
     "$elemMatch": {
       "code": "opt1"
     }
   }
 }, {
   "$inc": {
     "answers.$.votes": 1
   }
 })
```